# How to run OpenVPN for Docker on a Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, vpn, storage, docker

I am trying to add a VPN to my Raspberry Pi NAS, that I have created, so I can access it away from home while still securing my network.

I am currently going through the OpenVPN for Docker walk through: https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn/blob/master/README.md and when I try to run the following command:

```
docker run -v $OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn --rm kylemanna/openvpn ovpn_genconfig -u udp://VPN.SERVERNAME.COM
```

I get this error:

```
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/a                                                                                                   rm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
exec /usr/local/bin/ovpn_genconfig: exec format error
```

and when adding `--platform linux/amd64/v8`

I just get:

```
exec /usr/local/bin/ovpn_genconfig: exec format error.
```

NAS Build: Raspberry Pi 4 (128 GB SD, 8 GB RAM), External HDD 1 TB, Rasbian OS lite 64, and Open Media Vault as my NAS OS.

Is there a way I can fix this so the command goes through, or isn't this a viable option to secure my home NAS?

Comment: You are trying to run something for an Intel CPU. The Pi is ARM

Comment: Would changing --platform to ARM solve this issue? sudo docker run -v $OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn --rm kylemanna/openvpn ovpn_genconfig -u udp://ausrbp01a.duckdns.org --platform linux/arm64/v8

Comment: Now I'm getting "docker: invalid spec: :/etc/openvpn: empty section between colons."

Comment: Unable to find image 'kylemanna/openvpn:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from kylemanna/openvpn
Digest: sha256:643531abb010a088f1e23a1c99d44f0bd417a3dbb483f809caf4396b5c9829a0
Status: Image is up to date for kylemanna/openvpn:latest
docker: image with reference docker.io/kylemanna/openvpn:latest was found but does not match the specified platform: wanted linux/arm64/v8, actual: linux/amd64.
See 'docker run --help'.

Comment: Even after fixing the invalid spec error and specifying the CPU to arm64 it looks like it still won't work since this isn't meant for a PI CPU.

Comment: Which is what my Comment said.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Anthony. Did you already take the [tour]? Comments are not meant for discussions or to provide additional information about your question. If you want to improve the question, please [edit] it and add the relevant details. Code and error messages in comments are hard to read, and comments are not kept forever. The question should be understandable without reading the comment. Please read [ask]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using giggio 's fork of openvpn "giggio/openvpn-arm"